# drupal 7 image upload field not showing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

So i have a bit of an issue. My image upload field and widget are randomly disappearing. When i clear system cache, everything works perfectly but then after 24hrs/48hrs, the image upload field just disappears. All the php setting are set properly, files sizes and everything. I'm attaching 2 images to show you the difference.

Please help if you know how to fix this issue. It's not a duplicate, files are not being deleted, upload field/ widget is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Cron executes commands at specified intervals. These commands are called "cron jobs." Cron is available on Unix, Linux and Mac servers. Windows servers use a Scheduled Task to execute commands. Thus you can set your system cache to be cleared automatically, say every day.

Comment: Thanks Kosta. I know about cron, but i was hoping not to clear system cache too often as it is going to be a community site and would love not to clear cache too often for performance reasons. It is a great suggestion, thanks